# Message inbox doesn't remember "All" or "Unread" selection

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, user-experience, global-inbox

At the top of the new inbox, there's a dropdown where you can select if you want to see "All" or only your "Unread" notifications.

When you pick "Unread" and then reload the page, it doesn't stay on "Unread".

> [image]
> [image]

Please store this choice.

Comment: Feedback regarding the new inbox should be posted as an answer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/196432. That the setting is not remembered has already been reported at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384202/196432.

Comment: I didn't know there was a Meta SE announcement about this, it's almost as if we should have that in the sidebar here.

Comment: @Cerbrus There may be a problem with the featured sidebar actually.